# Problemas al actualizar de gulp 3 a 4: Task function must be specified

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-4

Estaba programado en gulp 3 pero al actualizarlo dejo de funcionar y ahora aparece esto al correr el comando de gulp:

```
assert.js:348
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
    at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (C:\Users\alext\Desktop\Platzigram\node_modules\undertaker\lib\set-task.js:10:3)
    at Gulp.task (C:\Users\alext\Desktop\Platzigram\node_modules\undertaker\lib\task.js:13:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\alext\Desktop\Platzigram\gulpfile.js:31:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

La versión es:

```
gulp -v
[20:34:05] CLI version 2.0.1
[20:34:05] Local version 4.0.0
```

Mi código de gulpfile.js es:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass'); 
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var babel = require('babelify');
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');

gulp.task('styles', function(){
  gulp
    .src('index.scss')
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(rename('app.css'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})

gulp.task('assets', function(){
    gulp
    .src('assets/*')
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
    browserify('./src/index.js')
    .transform(babel)
    .bundle()
    .pipe(source('index.js'))
    .pipe(rename('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})

gulp.task('default', ['styles','assets','scripts']);
```

Antes de que apareciera esto, todo funcionaba, estaba bien pero cuando se ejecutaba me decía que tenia 5 vulnerabilidades, los cuales al arreglarlos me mandaba el error de al principio.

Comment: Hay un [hilo sobre este problema](https://github.com/gulpjs/undertaker/issues/54) en el soporte de gulp en github. El usuario ku3mich explica que ocurre porque lo que era `gulp.task(name, deps, func)` en gulp 3 ha sido remplazado en gulp 4 con  `gulp.task(name, gulp.{series|parallel}(deps, func))`. En el mismo hilo hay varios enlaces explicando con más detalle por qué ocurre. Prueba eso para ver si es la causa del problema que encuentras. Un saludo.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Tuve el mismo problema, sucede que ahora gulp@4 tiene parametros adicionales que hace que migres un poco la sintaxis de tus tareas, pero que para bien ahora es mas ordenado.
Te dejo un enlace [ingles] con mas detalles:
https://codeburst.io/switching-to-gulp-4-0-271ae63530c0

En fin, ahora debes usar lo siguiente

```js
let gulp = require('gulp');
let sass = require('gulp-sass');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');

sass.compiler = require('node-sass');

gulp.task('styles', () => {
    return gulp.src('app.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(rename('app.css'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});


gulp.task('assets', () => {
    gulp.src('assets/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
})

gulp.task('watch', () => {
    gulp.watch('app.scss', gulp.series('styles'));
    gulp.watch('asset/*', gulp.series('assets'));
});

gulp.task('default', gulp.parallel('styles', 'assets'));
```

espero te haya ayudado